# Extracting information from $?

Tags: perl

Can you please provide good explanation about the following perl code snippet. I got some idea from google but still lots of basic confusion is there. great help if you can provide small notes on it

```
$exit_value  = $? >> 8;
$signal_num  = $? & 127;
$dumped_core = $? & 128;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Quoting [The Doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

> **$?**
>
> The status returned by the last pipe close, backtick (`` ) command,
> successful call to wait() or waitpid(), or from the system() operator.
> This is just the 16-bit status word returned by the traditional Unix
> wait() system call (or else is made up to look like it). Thus, the
> exit value of the subprocess is really ($?>> 8 ), and $? & 127 gives
> which signal, if any, the process died from, and $? & 128 reports
> whether there was a core dump.

`>> 8` gives us the higher byte of a 16-bit word.

`& 127` is essentially the same as `& 0b01111111`, giving out the lower 7-bit part of that word.

`& 128` is the same as `& 0b10000000`, which is basically checking for the 8th bit of the result.

Answer (score 6):

See [`perldoc -f system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html):

```
if ($? == -1) {
    print "failed to execute: $!\n";
}
elsif ($? & 127) {
    printf "child died with signal %d, %s coredump\n",
        ($? & 127),  ($? & 128) ? 'with' : 'without';
}
else {
    printf "child exited with value %d\n", $? >> 8;
}
```

The `$?` semantics are taken from the `wait` system call, see [`man 2 wait`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/wait/).

Comment: I would go a bit further about the `$? >> 8`, as this last 8 bit are usually a signed value: `($exit) = unpack("c", pack("S", ($? >> 8)))`.

Comment: @Ouki, `pack "S"` expects a 16-bit value, but I sincerely doubt that `$? >> 8` is 16-bits (because that would make the whole number 3 bytes long). But lets say it is for a second. Then you corrupt the number by only unpacking 8 of the 16 bits. That code is incorrect.

Comment: This is not, but `pack ("c", ($? >> 8))` will get you a warning.

Answer (score 3):

```
use POSIX qw( WEXITSTATUS WIFEXITED );

if( WIFEXITED($?) ) {
    print "The exit status was ", WEXITSTATUS($?), "\n";
}
```

See also [`WIFSIGNALED`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#WIFSIGNALED) and [`WTERMSIG`](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html#WTERMSIG).

Another useful C macro is [`WCOREDUMP`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Process-Completion-Status.html#index-WCOREDUMP-3189), documented in the GNU C library as (with added emphasis)

> `WCOREDUMP(status)`
>
> returns true if the child produced  a  core  dump.   This  macro should  only  be  employed  if  WIFSIGNALED returned true.  **This macro is not specified in POSIX.1-2001** and is not  available  on some  Unix  implementations  (e.g.,  AIX, SunOS).  Only use this enclosed in `#ifdef WCOREDUMP` … `#endif`.

Since [version 5.10.0](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/commit/e5218da503dbb4980410e0018f4cc5dcba3ea666?f=perl.h), perl [includes `WCOREDUMP`](http://perl5.git.perl.org/perl.git/blobdiff/6b09c1601036c61459334bdedef5d7e29e07fcaf..e5218da503dbb4980410e0018f4cc5dcba3ea666:/perl.h) in its computation of the value of `$?` if the macro is available on your system, as documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24CHILD_ERROR):

> Thus, the exit value of the subprocess is really `($?>> 8)`, and `$? & 127` gives which signal, if any, the process died from, and `$? & 128` reports whether there was a core dump.